# Hackban command

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
  @commands.command(aliases=['ckick'])
  @commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
  @commands.cooldown(1,3,BucketType.user)
  async def chunkkick(self, ctx, members: commands.Greedy[discord.Member]):
      if len(members) <= 1:
           embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, you can only input 2 or more users. [-ban]", color=discord.Color.orange())
           return await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
      if len(members) > 20:
           embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, cannot kick more than 20 users at a time.", color=discord.Color.orange())
           return await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
      if member.id == ctx.author.id:
          embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, you can't kick yourself.", color=discord.Color.orange())
          await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
          return
      if member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role:
          embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, targets role in the hierarchy is higher than yours.", color=discord.Color.orange())
          await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
      if ctx.me.top_role <= member.top_role:
          embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, my role in the hierarchy lesser than targets.", color=discord.Color.orange())
          await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
      if member.id == ctx.guild.owner:
          embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, owner is unkickable.", color=discord.Color.orange())
          await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
          return
      else:
          join_members = ", ".join(str(member.id) for member in members)
          embed = discord.Embed(description="<:ocheckmark:839069223749812264>  "+f"**Successfully chunk kicked {join_members}**", color=discord.Color.orange())
          for member in members:
              await member.kick(reason=f"{ctx.author} | User was in a chunk kick")
          await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
```

Error: `local variable 'member' defined before assignment`
Im trying to make a chunkban command (I rewrote my old one)
it worked before adding the if statements, I tried `member = for member in members` it didnt work.

Comment: What do you mean 'HackBan'? What's the usecase of this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do all the `if`s using `member` in a `for member in members:` loop. Also use `elif` instead of `if`, since you are only kicking the member if it's not the owner at the moment:

```py
@commands.command(aliases=['ckick'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
@commands.cooldown(1,3,BucketType.user)
async def chunkkick(self, ctx, members: commands.Greedy[discord.Member]):
    if len(members) <= 1:
       embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, you can only input 2 or more users. [-ban]", color=discord.Color.orange())
       return await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
    elif len(members) > 20:
       embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, cannot kick more than 20 users at a time.", color=discord.Color.orange())
       return await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Your chunkkick summary.", color=discord.Color.orange())
    for member in members: # do that for every member
        if member.id == ctx.author.id:
          embed.add_field(name=member.display_name, value="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, you can't kick yourself.")
          return
        elif member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role:
          embed.add_field(name=member.display_name, value="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, targets role in the hierarchy is higher than yours.")
        elif ctx.me.top_role <= member.top_role:
          embed.add_field(name=member.display_name, value="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, my role in the hierarchy lesser than targets.")
        elif member.id == ctx.guild.owner:
          embed.add_field(name=member.display_name, value="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, owner is unkickable.")
          return
        else:
            await member.kick(reason=f"{ctx.author} | User was in a chunk kick")
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
```

I also changed it to only send one embed, and not one embed per user.